# How to assign dynamic text styles in Xcode 11?

Tags: interface-builder, xcode11, dynamic-type-feature

*Edit: **Probable Bug**. Seeking fix or workaround…*

How can I get the system’s text styles to be available in the interface builder when using Xcode 11?

I just started using Xcode 11 this week. In the interface builder (storyboard mode), when I go to assign a dynamic type text style to a Label or Button, using the Font -> Style pop-up, all the text styles are missing from the popup menu.

[image: screenshot of Font Style popup menu, missing text styles]

I do have the Dynamic Type “Automatically Adjusts Font” checkbox checked, as well.

I’m not sure if this is a bug, an intentional change I can’t find documentation for, or something else.

The expected behaviour is described in Apple’s developer documentation “[Scaling Fonts Automatically](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically)”. Specifically, in the “Configuring Text Styles Using Interface Builder” section.

Further exploration: I’ve tried it with new projects, old projects (from Xcode 10), projects targeting iOS 12.2 and 13.1. All had the same problem of no text styles in the popup menu.

Comment: What do you mean *dynamic text style*? what font did you pick?

Comment: Mojtaba: I mean the text styles that were there in Xcode 10, like “Headline” and “Body”, used for dynamic type scaling, as described, and illustrated, in Apple’s documentation on “Scaling Fonts Automatically”: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically

(and, yes, Apple’s terminology here is a bit confusing as their “Dynamic Type” in reference to text has nothing to do with the more common use of “dynamic types” when referring to variables)

Comment: What font do you pick? I can see those in my Xcode 11

Comment: I have the same problem as you, Grant. I just updated to Catalina yesterday, and I think the styles were there prior to that.

Comment: I don’t pick any font (I leave it at the default “System”) prior to trying to set a text style. I haven’t upgraded to Catalina yet—still on Mojave (10.14.6). My Xcode version is the latest: 11.1. So, if Steve and I are seeing the same problem, it’s probably not tied to the OS and is instead a bug in Xcode.

Comment: I downloaded Xcode 11.2 beta and opened my project in it. The dynamic type styles show up. Reverting back to Xcode 11.1 and the styles are _also_ there, now. For what it's worth, I filed a bug with Apple if anyone else runs into this (FB7368959).

Comment: The text styles “magically” returned a couple days ago. I’ve no idea what brought them back (I didn’t reinstall Xcode, or the beta, or an older version, or anything; and no system updates in that time). I guess this is another one to chalk up to the mysterious and powerful Magic Lightning at the heart of all computers. ‍♂️

Comment: @GrantNeufeld: On what kind of machine did you experience the problem? I am having the same issue and even a fresh install of Catalina and a fresh install of Xcode 11.2 did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Georg: iMac (Late 2013). I’m still on Mojave (macOS 10.14). The problem eventually just “went away” for me after some days—without any re-installs or anything. The problem came up (and disappeared) when I was using Xcode 11.1. I’ve installed Xcode 11.2 this week and it has not repeated the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bug in Xcode 11.1. I ran into the same thing and filed a bug with Apple (FB7368959). A colleague running Xcode 11.1 on Catalina did not have the same problem, nor did another running Xcode 11.1 on Mojave.

Here is a workaround that got me back on track: I opened the problematic project in both Xcode 10.3 and 11.2 beta. In both, the dynamic type styles were available in IB. I didn't change anything, but reverted to Xcode 11.1, and now the styles are there, too. Hopefully this works for Grant and anyone else that runs into this annoyance.

**Edit Mar. 17, 2020:** This problem has reoccurred for me on Xcode 11.3.1. It seemed to happen with a specific project, and the problem spread to a second machine as soon as I opened that project. My workaround didn't help when I opened the project in 11.4 beta 3.

Comment: Xcode 11.0 on Mojave was fine but with Xcode 11.1 I experience the same bug. Xcode 11.2 beta did not help me though :( This bug makes Xcode 11.1 unusable for me at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I experience the same problem when upgrading from Xcode 11.0 to Xcode 11.1 or 11.2 beta 2:

**Xcode 11.0:**

[image: Text styles are available]

**Xcode 11.1:**

[image]

I also filed a bug report (FB7415999) with Apple and also opened an issue with them.

**My curren solution at the moment is a downgrade to Xcode 11.0 for UI development and a parallel install of Xcode 11.2 beta for on device runs **

Comment: Even a fresh install of Catalina on my dev machine did not help. In new projects as well as in my current projects I do not have text styles in Xcode 11.2 (current version in the app store).